# XCode: how to install on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7?

Tags: macos, catalina, xcode, mac-appstore

1. I have here a dozen Apple computers running on "MacOS Catalina 10.15.7";
2. These Apple computers cannot be updated using the built-in system update application;
3. I need to install XCode on them;
4. The App Store offers only one version of XCode;
5. The version of XCode offered by the App Store requires "MacOS 13".

Which ways do I have to I install an older version of XCode ([ideally, Xcode 12.4](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)) on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7?

Comment: It needs to be 12.4?  Xcode 12.5 is downloadable from the portal.

Comment: @MarcWilson [The linked page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) says that XCode "12.4" is the last version still supporting MacOS Catalina 10.15. [The linked page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) says that XCode "12.5" only supports MacOS Big Sur "11" and newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XCode 12.4](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode%2012.4) is available from the Developer Portal.

[image]

Comment: "Sorry, you cannot view this page. The Apple ID you signed in with does not have permission to view this page. If you’re currently a member of the Apple Developer Program, you or your Account Holder may need to update your account by agreeing to the latest license agreement in order to access this page. To view your current membership status and benefits, visit your account."

Comment: Yeah, you may have to sign up.  It's free.

Comment: Marc: I tested your answer from a fresh Catalina install and found the link does not work directly from your answer. I changed your answer to goto the Apple webpage with the same link. This does require a login with Apple ID. Selecting the link given on the Apple webpage will result in the download Xcode 12.4.